# to make value selected obtained from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

my code is as follows 
and m getting the value from javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(desig){
document.getElementById("designation").value=desig;
}
</script>



<select id="designation" name="designation">    
 <?php
        while($row_address=mysql_fetch_array($loc))
                         {
          <option value="" selected="selected"><?=$row_address['location']?></option>
          <?php }?>
        </select>
```

but m not able to find the solution to tick that particular value obtained from javascript
in dropdown

Answer (score 0):

I <s>tested your code</s> tested a simplified version of your code and it works fine. The one thing to note is that you must give it a value that does exist as an option.

Here is the code i used in full:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <select id="designation" name="designation">    
      <option value="some value" selected="selected">some text</option>
      <option value="some value 2" selected="selected">some other text</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function show(desig){
    document.getElementById("designation").value=desig;
  }

  show('some value 2');
</script>
```

Note that if I called `show('blah')` it would not have worked since that isn't a valid option value.

**Edit:** your php code seems to have a few syntax issues and you also do not specify a `value=` property other than an empty string - which is probably a big part of why it isn't working. Try

```
<?php
    while($row_address=mysql_fetch_array($loc)) {
        $location = $row_address['location'];
        echo "<option value='$location'>$location</option>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: m using while loop..is it becoz of that m not able to get

Comment: @namratha first of all, I'm confused as to why you have `<?=$row_address['location']?>` in those tags WITHIN a `<?php` tag. Forget the javascript - does your code produce a dropdown box with the correct options?

Comment: @namratha see my latest edit, maybe that will clear things up a bit. When you test your page you can right click the select box and click 'Inspect Element' (if you're on Chrome or FF) and make sure that the resultant html is correct.